# How to create a 2d array with array of objects inside columns in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multidimensional-array, arrayobject

I want to predefine the 2d-array containing an array of objects like this below image:
[image]

I am trying this way:

```
var grid = [];
iMax = 3;
jMax = 2;
count = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < iMax; i++) {
      grid[i] = [];

      for (let j = 0; j < jMax; j++) {
        grid[i][j] = count;
        count++;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and where you're stuck?

Comment: I know in java how to do it. But in javascript unable to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're building up the two-dimensional array, but you are filling the rows with `numbers` (i.e. your setting the `count`) instead of an array of objects. So if you want to achieve the exact same structure as provided in the screenshot, you can do:

```js
const rows = 4;
const cols = 4;
const elementCount = 3;



function buildGrid(rows,cols, elementCount) {
  const grid = [];
  for(let i=0; i < rows; i++) {
    grid[i] = [];
    for(let j=0; j < cols; j++) {
      grid[i].push(Array.from({length:elementCount}, () => ({})));
    }

  }
  return grid;
}

const grid = buildGrid(rows,cols,elementCount);
console.log(grid);
```